# unhandled exception whith cvCreatImage in visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, opencv, unhandled-exception

I am using openCV2.3.1 on windows7 in visual studio 2010, and whenever i try to create an image with cvCreateImage() it gives an unhandled exception. But when I try my code on code blocks it runs without errors.

here is my code

```
imgToTreate = cvCreateImage (cvSize (250, 250), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
cvResize(img, imgToTreate);
```

I don't understand why, I need your help...

thank you !

Answer (score 0):

You need to check that:

- `img` is loaded correctly in Visual Studio (you use relative paths, don't you?)
- `img` has the same type and number of channels as `imgToTreate`.